# Codeigniter 3 upgrade session lock causing issues

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

We've recently upgraded an old Codeigniter app from 2.1.0 to 3.1.9, and everything has gone smoothly. Except, that the new session locking is causing issues and I'm wondering the proper way to fix it.

The app uses AJAX heavily, however most of the AJAX calls don't write to the session and don't seem to break it.

Here is an example of the issue: there is a GUI with checkboxes, and when the input is changed (a checkbox is checked or unchecked) an AJAX call was made. On the other end of that AJAX call which boxes were checked were written to session so that they would be remembered from visit to visit. However, if you checked/unchecked multiple boxes causing multiple AJAX calls to go out, you would end up getting logged out. Similar behavior has been discovered around the app, all where session writes are happening.

I've tried implementing `session_write_close()` as suggested by the [Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#a-note-about-concurrency) but that only half worked in some spots, and caused more issues in area where there were no issues before. The app has a few endpoints that do all the work and all work flows share, so fixing the endpoint where the session writes are happening with `session_write_close()` breaks other script calls when they continue to need the session.

The short term solution I've come up with is to debounce the AJAX calls (which helps but doesn't solve the problem by itself) and to disable inputs until the AJAX call has finished.

Is there a better long term solution? Ultimately this app is being phased out, so spending a long time rewriting it isn't feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only long-term solution is to properly use `session_write_close()`.

As you undoubtedly understand, session data is locked so only one script at any time can write to the session's persistent datastore. Session locking prevents hard to troubleshoot concurrency bugs and is more secure.

Without seeing your implementation it's really hard, er... impossible to offer any precise advice. Here are some things to consider that might help sort out the mess.

Either do *ALL* or *NONE* of the session writes in the AJAX response functions. (By "AJAX response function" I mean the PHP `controller/method` value of the AJAX url.)

With the *ALL* approach call `session_write_close()` in the "main" script before making any AJAX requests. Keep in mind that `$_SESSION` is not affected by `session_write_close()`. All `$_SESSION` items in the *main* script will remain accessible so you can reliably read the values. However, *changes* made to `$_SESSION` will not be written because, as far as PHP is concerned, the session is closed. But that's only true for the script that calls `session_write_close()`.

With the *NONE* approach you may still need to read session data. In that case it would be wise to have the AJAX response functions call `session_write_close` as soon as possible to minimize the time concurrent requests are blocked. The call is more important for functions that require significant time to execute. If the script execution time is short then the explicit call to `session_write_close()` is not needed. If at all possible, i.e. no need to read session data, then not loading the `session` class might result in cleaner code. It would definitely eliminate any chance of concurrent request blocking.

Don't try to test session behavior by using multiple tabs to the same app on the same browser.

Consider using `$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;` and then explicitly call `$this->sess_regenerate((bool) config_item('sess_regenerate_destroy'));` when and where it makes sense that the session id needs to be changed, i.e. right after login; right after a redirect to a "sensitive" page; etc.

What follows next is offered with a large amount of trepidation. I've tested this using the "files" driver, but not extensively. So, buyer beware.

I found that it is possible to "re-start" a session by calling the PHP function `session_start()`  after `session_write_close()` has been used. CodeIgniter will open and read the session datastore and rebuild the `$_SESSION` superglobal. It's now possible to change session data and it will be written when script execution ends - or with another call to `session_write_close()`.

This makes sense because `session_write_close()` does not "do" anything to the CodeIgniter `session` object. The class is still instantiated and configured. CodeIgniter's custom `SessionHandlerInterface` is used to open, read, and write session data after `session_start()` is called.

Maybe this apparent functionality can be used to solve your problems. In case I wasn't clear earlier - use at your own risk!

Comment: Unfortunately this is legacy software that was never written with session locking in mind. Script A calls Script B which has session writes, but Script A also calls Script C after B which has more writes, and Script D calls Script C by itself, and Script A can be called by itself or as apart of Script E. So there's no good place to put `session_write_close()`, unless I experiment with `session_start()`. As it's being phased out, spending the time on rewriting it correctly is likely not on the table. Thanks!