# Codeigniter 3 session locking causing high number database connections

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter 3 sessions using mysql driver. SELECT GET_LOCK(sess,300) is called to prevent scripts from modifying session data at same time.

This works fine until a user goes crazy and makes a bunch of requests causing all of these connections to pile up and eventually slow down database until they are all released

1. If I use redis, files, or memcached driver, will this take load off database? How do these drivers lock? Which backend is recommend for ALB with 4 web servers?
2. Is there a sane way to stick with database driver and prevent query pileup?

Comment: Yes, go for `files` driver. if you need even faster, check [this](https://eddmann.com/posts/storing-php-sessions-file-caches-in-memory-using-tmpfs/)

Comment: I don’t see file driver working with multiple web servers

Comment: If you are using load balancer, you also require config `Sticky Session`

Comment: Yes, Redis or memcached will take the load off the database (which tends to be the biggest bottleneck). It would help to know what kind of intense database session modifications are being performed (from your question, I assume you're not just using sessions for keeping sessions alive (which does not really require locking). Like you said, using the files driver is not the best idea when you have multiple app servers (even if you use sticky sessions) because if a server goes down, those users will loose their session info

Comment: In codeigniter GET_LOCK('SESSION_ID',300) is called every page load so no 2 scripts for same session can modify session at same time.

Comment: @ChrisMuench similar talk I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483367/codeigniter-3-upgrade-session-lock-causing-issues)

Comment: @ChrisMuench Have you found a solution for your problem? I am seeing the same thing happening on my application. The setup is in with a LoadBalancer, two apache web servers and a RDS MySQL. About once every two weeks we see a sudden spike in get_lock calls for the same session to the database. Concurrent connections spike from 5-10 to 400 in one minute. Then everything recovers after 5 minutes. (I assume because the 300 second time limit). I'm thinking of reducing the 300 to something like 60 seconds to at least speed up the recovery.

Comment: I'm using database sessions, no sticky sessions. And maybe this problem is different, because I don't see a spike of 400 requests in the logs of our load balancer. So it could be happening between the web servers and the database.

Comment: I ended up using pt-kill and kill any select queries running for more than 15 seconds. Another solution is you could use redis for sessions. See post by blasto333 @ https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-75231-post-370888.html#pid370888

Comment: @webtopf I am now going back to redis as I think this will work better. What was your solution?

Comment: @ChrisMuench I have the exact same issue. Did you end up using redis? Did it solve the issue?

Comment: Yes see this https://gist.github.com/blasto333/f06907ca9ce0982d76cc091869d6ed4e

You will need to modify for your use. I am using php redis session handling